# Will a Mac boot with Clonezilla?

Tags: usb, startup

The goal is to upgrade a Mac's hard drive to an SSD.

Is it possible to boot [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) from a USB stick on a Mac [(iMac 2007/Mac 7,1](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=iMac7%2C1)) to clone a mechanical HDD to a SDD?  I do not have access to the target machine in my home / office and will have very limited amount of valuable time on the target machine.

Although there are reports of [booting from USB](https://www.isumsoft.com/it/how-to-boot-a-mac-from-a-bootable-usb-drive/), I am unable to find instances of **booting a Mac from USB Clonezilla**.  My concern is that there is some obstacle to booting Clonezilla or other hurdle that would prevent upgradomg the HDD to a SDD.  I would prefer that advance experience inform me that it is not possible because of X,Y,orZ so I do not waste my limited time on the target machine.

Although I have performed the clone exercise with other methods, my curiosity prompts the question: the hope is that someone has actually performed the task with Clonezilla or knows enough to confidently claim Clonezilla is possible.

UPDATE: I do not have access to said target machine & it is not mine to experiment with as I please. I am reluctant to experiment on machines that are not mine to satisfy ***intellectual curiosity***.  The target machine is not mine. I am open to new ideas and appreciate suggestions that ultimately serve the goal & do not necessarily address the question.

Comment: Why not just use **Disk Utility** while booted from **macOS Recovery** from a  **macOS** USB Installer?

Comment: The issue, for me at least, is whether or not you *tried.*  you obviously know how to use Clonezilla, so I don’t understand why the unwillingness to create a bootable Clonezilla USB and give it a go.  In the 14 hrs from when you first posted and I cast my reopen vote, you could have attempted this several times.  What is really poignant here is you state you “don’t want to waste your limited time.”  So, our time isn’t as valuable as yours?

Comment: Might be easer to put the SSD into the external enclosure first, boot from HDD and mirror it to the SSD. Or, as already mentioned, boot into Recovery and clone the disk from there.

Comment: @Allan, Thank you for casting the reopen vote.  As reassurance for your vote: I do not have access to said target machine & it is not mine to experiment with as I please.  I am reluctant to experiment on machines that are not mine to satisfy intellectual curiosity

Comment: Because of some of the edits and wording I just have to ask... Is this your **Mac** or someones else's?

Comment: What's with the down-votes people? +1 to counter last down-vote.

Comment: IMO The easiest and best way to handle this it to put the **SSD** in an enclosure and attach it to the **Mac**, then boot the **Mac** using a **macOS USB Installer**. From **macOS Recovery** you can use **Disk Utility** to restore a _volume_ from another _volume_ and when you restore from one _volume_ to another _volume_, it makes an exact copy of the original. You'd select the _disk_ itself, not e.g. **Macintosh HD**. Then boot the **Mac** from the **SSD** and if it works (it should), then swap out the _disks_.

Comment: @user3439894  Good questions:the target Mac is not mine.   It would seem that the `macOS USB installer' method would be less risky.  Is there a link to this procedure?

Comment: If the target machine isn’t yours and you don’t have access, why are you looking for untested methods?  Why not go with what is already known to work (i.e. CCC)?  Also, you don’t need the actual target machine to see if this will work, a bbotable USB can be tested on *any* Mac.

Comment: Finally, I don’t recommend this approach.  You’re cloning a drive with a file system optimized for spinning disks onto a solid state disk.  Not a good idea to begin with.  You should do a clean reinstall for best results.

Comment: I have to say considering the age of the **Mac**, and it only officially supports **OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)** as the newest version of the **OS**, I wouldn't waste any time or money on it! Also, anytime you start messing with a system that old, to many times have I seen things go wrong even when done professionally. **Time to upgrade to a newer Mac!**

Comment: It is an older device and is used by a retiree to play music.  I think he has a Macbook Air for web browsing, etc.   Maybe running lUbuntu on the older Mac is a good option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, it's doable!

Testing on a **MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)**, as it's the oldest **Mac** I have access to today…

I went to https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php and clicked on [alternative stable - 20200428-focal](https://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=alternative), then in the next *window* left **1**, **2**, **3** as set and clicked the **DOWNLOAD** button.

While the **zip** archive was downloading I prepared the **USB** *drive* in **Disk Utility** so it's a single **FAT32** partition with an **Master Boot Record**. The output below from **Terminal** shows how it should look, although the `disk` number may vary on your *system*:

```
$ diskutil list disk3
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk3
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED                8.0 GB     disk3s1
$
```

Unzip the downloaded **zip** archive to the *root* of the **USB** *drive* while maintaining the *hierarchical directory structure* contained within the **zip** archive, as shown in **Terminal** using `ls -al`:

```
$ ls -al
total 128
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 me   staff   4096 May 31 07:22 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 root  wheel    136 May 31 07:02 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff   4096 May 31 07:22 .disk
-rwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff    188 Apr 28 22:56 Clonezilla-Live-Version
drwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff   4096 May 31 07:22 EFI
-rwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff  18092 Aug 11  2015 GPL
drwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff   4096 May 31 07:22 boot
drwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff   4096 May 31 07:20 home
drwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff   4096 May 31 07:22 live
drwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff   4096 May 31 07:22 syslinux
drwxrwxrwx  1 me   staff   4096 May 31 07:20 utils
$
```

Then booted the **Mac** with **Clonezilla Live** on **USB** by pressing the **Option** *key* at *startup*, selecting **EFI Boot** and pressed **Enter**.

## However …

That all said, while it is possible to boot a **Mac** with **Clonezilla Live** on **USB**; nonetheless, I would just use **Disk Utility** while booted from **macOS Recovery** from a **macOS USB Installer**, and use it to mirror the *drives* using the **Restore** button.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the results of `cat /proc/partitions` and 'df -h`

Comment: @gatorback, Considering what an inconvenience this was to do it the first place and the fact that on a **Retina Display** the text is so small I had to use a magnifying glass just to read the screen past a certain point in the boot process, sorry but it's not going to happen unless you boot it on your system.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your results.  I appreciate the effort.  Credit awarded.